# Pivot table in Hive

Tags: hive

I'm new to hadoop and hive. if anyone worked with a concept of **pivot in hive** then please share with me.

Eg: the data from teradata or oracle is unpivoted, these data should be pivoted in hive. so **how to apply the concept of pivot in hive**...

Thanks in advance,

Tamil

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you have seen the link below
http://www.flytxt.com/community/general-discussion/pivot-table-in-hive/
It tries to explain the concept in detail

Comment: Thanks Joe. ya i referred to that.The approach is limited for finite number of columns. Am also looking solution for the same. another approach is to go with case statements(but number is 388)

Comment: @Joe 404, the link is dead.