# Efficiently join same table on different columns with Hive

Tags: join, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to work this out as efficiently as possible.

Say I have a table, **ids**, with a single column containing a list of integers, let's call it 'ids':

```
ids
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

And I have another table, **items**, with a few columns of integers:

```
item1    item2    item3    item4
5        2        2        4
9        2        1        19
0        25       9        2
```

What I want to do is select all columns from table2, but I want a NULL if the value is not in the 'ids' table. So my result would look like this:

```
item1    item2    item3    item4
5        2        2        4
NULL     2        1        NULL
0        NULL     NULL     2
```

I can do this by selecting from **items** and joining to **ids** for each of the columns:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ids1.id IS NOT NULL THEN items.item1 ELSE NULL,
       CASE WHEN ids2.id IS NOT NULL THEN items.item2 ELSE NULL,
       CASE WHEN ids3.id IS NOT NULL THEN items.item3 ELSE NULL,
       CASE WHEN ids4.id IS NOT NULL THEN items.item4 ELSE NULL,
FROM items
LEFT OUTER JOIN ids ids1 ON (ids1.id = items.item1),
LEFT OUTER JOIN ids ids2 ON (ids2.id = items.item2),
LEFT OUTER JOIN ids ids3 ON (ids3.id = items.item3),
LEFT OUTER JOIN ids ids4 ON (ids4.id = items.item4)
```

Unfortunately, when these tables grow large (millions of rows), it's quite a drag to have to join to the same table 4 times. Is there a faster or more efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to take a look at this thread 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412422/pivot-table-in-hive

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example cycling through normalizing it, left join to test against ids, and finally pivoting it back.

```
create table ids ( id int );
insert ids values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);
create table items (itemid int, item1 int, item2 int, item3 int, item4 int);
insert items select
1,5,2,2,4 union all select
2,9,2,1,19 union all select
3,0,25,9,2;

select *
from (
    select u.itemid,ids.id,u.item
    from items
    unpivot (id for item in (item1,item2,item3,item4)) u
    left join ids on ids.id = u.id
) x
pivot (max(id) for item in (item1,item2,item3,item4)) p
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. Unfortunately, my understanding is that Hive does not support PIVOT or UNPIVOT. Can you find any other approaches to this? Thanks!